# display select list as an image list

Tags: 7, entities

I want to make my site more user friendly and so I would like to replace select list with an image list. 
Is it possible to display ordinary select list as an image list?
Is there a module that would allow me to do so or do I need a custom code for this fetaure?

Comment: check this module https://drupal.org/project/finder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is in fact a module that can do this. It's the [Select with style](http://drupal.org/project/select_with_style) module.

Comment: doesn't work in chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use some jQuery help for displaying images as options in a select form element. Check out [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/16-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/) collection of plugins.

You may also have to implement your own Form API element type using [`hook_element_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7) to output the markup that your chosen jQuery plugin needs.

Lastly, you haven't said which select list you would like to change, but if it's an existing form, you might end up implementing [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

Comment: thank you, it seems there is no module to accomplish this. I am not a programmer so I think my solution would be to go for a list with radiobuttons and add images using css.